Colours displaying incorrectly in Photo Viewer?
I recently had to replace the screen on a laptop, pulled from the same model, and have run into a problem that didn't exist before the replacement. When I turned the laptop on afterwards everything was very bright and washed out. I went through calibration and got everything looking like it used to, but there was one problem: Windows Photo Viewer. For some reason, when images are opened in Photo Viewer it's like the contrast has been turned up or something. Images look as they should when opened in the installed photo editor, Gimp 2.6, as well as in Chrome and even in MS Paint just not in Photo Viewer. For example, when opening a drawing in the other programs where the subjects are wearing mostly black it's easy to see the outlines, shading, the lighter base shade of the clothes but when opened in Photo Viewer all of that is just completely flat black.
This hadn't been an issue with the previous screen, which is assumed to be the original. Before, regardless of where images were opened they always looked the same, even in Photo Viewer. This only started after replacing the screen. Unfortunately, simply switching back to the old screen isn't an option. It's no longer functional, which is why it needed replaced. And no matter how I calibrate the new one Photo Viewer doesn't look right.
So, how do I get Photo Viewer to display the images correctly like every other program?

what happens if you connect an external screen ?

@1NN I don't know. There isn't one available to try and the laptop doesn't have any ports that fit any of the cables I have anyway.

maybe this helps: https://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/269453-windows-7-pro-x64-bad-image-color-temperature-windows-photo-viewer.html - also go through the links in that thread

@1NN well... it's working now but I admit I have no idea how? I followed your link last night, went down the rabbit hole of different links there and tried the solution they had but it didn't work. When I opened Colour Management there  were no colour profiles listed at all, probably not a good thing, so I added the default one. I told it to use my setting. Even selected the default profile in the advanced tab. I restarted the laptop and nothing changed. The problem wasn't resolved. Being me, I figured that I must have made a mistake and tried again but it didn't help...

... I tried three times before I got frustrated and decided to deal with it in the morning. And when I came back in the morning Photo Viewer was displaying images correctly. It just worked. And I'm actually kind of angry about it? I don't know if the solution at the link helped or if I accidentally changed something that fixed it, wouldn't be the first time... They never mentioned anything about needing to give it a few hours, so I have no idea?

I'm glad you managed to resolve it. If you can, retrace your steps and write an answer, even if you don't know what exactly helped. I'm unable to test anything as I'm already on Windows 11.

@1NN I'm not really sure I could retrace my steps to figure out what worked. As far as I recall I didn't do anything after my failed attempts besides turn the laptop off for a few hours while I got some sleep. It was just working when I came back to it. I don't understand it at all. The best I could offer would just be what's already written in that link. Regardless though, shouldn't you post an answer so you can get the bounty?

Can you try adjusting graphics driver settings for image enhancement or color enhancement to see if it will fix it or not?
for intel it's Graphics Control Panel > Video

@ZoomMan2 You're a bit late to the party, my friend. It's already working again, I just don't know how that happened.
